# Pagespeed insights will not load updated version of my website

Tags: pagespeed-insights, google-pagespeed-insights-api

Hopefully someone can help.

Pagespeed insights will only show an old 'broken' version of my website. It's been completely fixed and updated now, but it still will not change on pagespeed insights.

I have cleared every cache imaginable and even downloaded firefox - but still the same issue. Strangely enough, it's also the same problem with gtmetrix and pingdom. I even tried with my wifes laptop and still nothing.

The only way i can get the updated reading is by using an incognito firefox window on my mobile phone - after downloading the firefox application. It's been so difficult to get help, because every person i speak to tries it on their computer and it works fine. It just seams to be a problem with all my devices.

Is there some kind of pagespeed insights cache i need to clear? I'm lost for ideas now and cannot think of anything else!

Comment: What happens if you go incognito on your PC? Unfortunately you will not likely get any help on this if you are saying it works for everyone else as we can't debug it for you. The fact that 3 different sites all give you the same result mean the only thing I can think of is you are using a CDN to serve your site and have not cleared / updated it properly. Share a URL and I will have a look but as I said, difficult to help if it works for everyone else but you I am afraid.

Comment: Hi James, Check your host entry Or nslookup where content is served from.  Also if  using any mod header browser plugins disable it .